# Avoid moving to initial position after Animation

Tags: android

I'm creating half circle image moving animation with specified radius.My code is working fine.But it moving to it's initial position after animation end.My code is below:

Inside Activity:

```
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation anim = new MyAnimation(image, 150); // radius = 150
            anim.setDuration(3000);
            anim.setFillEnabled(true);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            image.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    });
```

Animation Class:

```
public class MyAnimation extends Animation {

private View view;
private float cx, cy;           // center x,y position of circular path
private float prevX, prevY;     // previous x,y position of image during animation
private float r;                // radius of circle
private float prevDx, prevDy;


/**
 * @param view - View that will be animated
 * @param r - radius of circular path
 */
public MyAnimation(View view, float r){
    this.view = view;
    this.r = r;
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    // calculate position of image center
    int cxImage = width / 2;
    int cyImage = height / 2;
    cx = view.getLeft() + cxImage;
    cy = view.getTop() + cyImage;

    // set previous position to center
    prevX = cx+r;
    prevY = cy;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    if(interpolatedTime == 0){
        t.getMatrix().setTranslate(prevDx, prevDy);
        return;
    }

    float angleDeg = (interpolatedTime * 180f ) % 180;
    float angleRad = (float) Math.toRadians(angleDeg);

    // r = radius, cx and cy = center point, a = angle (radians)
    float x = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angleRad));
    float y = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angleRad));

    float dx = prevX - x;
    float dy = prevY - y;

    prevX = x;
    prevY = y;

    prevDx = dx;
    prevDy = dy;

    t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx, dy);

}
}
```

Please guide me to complete this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of animation listener `image.setX(image.getX()+2*radius)`.this will change the position of image.

Answer (score 0):

Start animation like this

```
image.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
```

and add listener to view, and onAnimationEnd change the view position

```
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: how to call the end view position from myAnimator ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set listener to solve this problem.

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
});
image.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Comment: how to call the end view position from myAnimator ?

Comment: you can set image view visibility gone when it reaches to the end.

Comment: Log value working in animation end. but  image.setVisibility(View.GONE); is not working.

Answer (score -1):

@Rathi J

Don't know Excat Answer..But i am trying.

I think you should replace :

```
anim.setFillAfter(true);
```

with this :

```
anim.setFillAfter(false);
```

Hope This will helps..(:

Comment: anim.setFillAfter(true); is used to fix position in Scale animation. but its not woking with custom animation. anim.setFillAfter(false) also not working :(

Comment: ooooppppssss :(